C++ condition variable doesn't block the thread on wait_until() using the time_poin::max()?
The below code doesn't block the thread and it gets into an infinite loop and keep printing
Waiting...
Waiting...
My idea is, the thread should block on the max() time and when it's set to now(), it should unblock the thread and do the business. Any ideas? I am using VS2013
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::condition_variable condVar;
std::mutex mut;
bool pred = false;
auto dueAt = std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point::max();

void threadFunc()
{
    for (;;)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
        dueAt = std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point::max();

        if (condVar.wait_until(lock, dueAt, [](){ return pred; }))
        {
            std::cout << "Ready..." << std::endl;
            pred = false;
            dueAt = std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point::max();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Waiting..." << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void notifierThread()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
            dueAt = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
            pred = true;
            std::cout << " Signalling..." << std::endl;
        }
        condVar.notify_one();
    }
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::thread t1(threadFunc);
    std::thread t2(notifierThread);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}


can't reproduce in vs2022, is there a reason you're using an 11 year old release?

It's legacy code base we are supporting. So does that mean it's wait_until() is not doing what it supposed to do on VS2013 then?

I don't understand when your wait_until call can ever return false (and print put Waiting...). When it is called, dueAt is set to max, so the timeout cannot be reached. And if the internal waiting in the loop is interrupted, the timeout is either still the same, or, if it has changed, then pred has changed to true as well and the loop ends.

It's currently printing Waiting all the time and if I add a sleep() in the else then it appear to work. I am just understand what's the right way of using a wait_until() that blocks a thread permanently and would unblocks after we signal it?

If you want an infinite wait why use wait_until at all? Why not just wait?

"using a wait_until() that blocks a thread permanently" — This does not make any sense.

@Alan Birtles, I have made that working using a wait() but the wait_until() gives us more control on when to actually unblock the thread by manipulating the due time.

@Daniel, When I say permanently blocked thread, I mean the thread remains blocked until we signal it.

I still don't understand your usecase, you signal the thread by changing pred and calling notify_one, changing the value of dueAt at that point doesn't do anything?

Exactly. In my opinion, your code is the same as if you replaced wait_until by wait (plus get rid of that branching). Changing dueAt in notifierThread doesn't affect anything in this program.

@Seektech Why do you think manipulating dueAt changes when wait_until wakes up?  You set it to dueAt = std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point::max(); before waiting every time.  Barring a bug in the std implementation, dueAt = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); does nothing.

Your compiler is old and has bugs?
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::condition_variable condVar;
std::mutex mut;
bool pred = false;
bool shutdown = false;
int result = 0;

void threadFunc()
{
  for (;;)
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);

    condVar.wait(lock, [](){ return pred || shutdown; });

    if (shutdown) {
      std::cout << "Shutdown!" << std::endl;
      break;
    }
    std::cout << "Ready... #" << result << std::endl;
    pred = false;
    ++result;
  }
}

void notifierThread()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
      pred = true;
      std::cout << " Signalling... #" << i << std::endl;
    }
    condVar.notify_one();
  }
}


int main()
{
    std::thread t1(threadFunc);
    std::thread t2(notifierThread);
    t2.join();
    while (true) {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mut);
      if (result == 5)
      {
        std::cout << " Signalling Shutdown!" << std::endl;
        shutdown = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    condVar.notify_one();
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}

here is a complete terminating version of your program that does not use dueAt.
Manipulating dueAt while you are .wait_untiling should do nothing (barring UB due to a race condition, which you avoided with a lock).  It appears your C++ std implementation has a bug.
What, exactly, you where trying to do isn't clear, so I converted your code into something that (probably) halts.
In practice, you can't assume that sending 5 signals this way results in 5 receptions, as the sleep(100 ms) isn't guaranteed to give the reader thread to read.  A more proper program would send a counter:
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::condition_variable condVar;
std::mutex mut;
int counter = 0;
bool shutdown = false;
int consumed = 0;

void threadFunc()
{
  for (;;)
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);

    auto old_count = counter;
    condVar.wait(lock, [old_count](){ return (counter != old_count) || shutdown; });

    if (shutdown) {
      std::cout << "Shutdown!" << std::endl;
      break;
    }
    std::cout << "Ready... #" << old_count << ".." << counter << std::endl;
    consumed = counter;
  }
}

void notifierThread()
{
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(250));
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    if (i%2)
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mut);
      ++counter;
      std::cout << " Signalling... #" << i << " with count " << counter << std::endl;
    }
    condVar.notify_one();
  }
}


int main()
{
    std::thread t1(threadFunc);
    std::thread t2(notifierThread);
    t2.join();
    while (true) {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mut);
      if (consumed == 5)
      {
        std::cout << " Signalling Shutdown!" << std::endl;
        shutdown = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    condVar.notify_one();
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}

here I make the producer be erratic, sometimes fast and sometimes slow.  The consumer can handle more than 1 signal at a time however.
